# JSOUP authentication in android returns Status=401

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I need to parse a webpage in android using jsoup.

However, it doesn't work for pages that need authentication. The error I get is `org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=401`

This is my code

```
try {
        Log.e("doInBackground","started");
        String url ="https://exampleurl.com";

        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String login = username + ":" + password;
        String encodedLogin;

        encodedLogin =  new String(Base64.encodeBase64(login.getBytes()));

        Log.e("encodedLogin",encodedLogin);

        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedLogin).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute(); // you might need to use "Method.POST" for the parameter for method

        Document doc = response.parse();

        if(doc!= null){
            Log.e("doc",doc.toString());
        } 

} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have also tried to replace `Method.GET` with `Method.POST`, still it didn't work.

Also tried using header and still it didn't work.

```
Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedLogin)
                .get();
```